Kubernetes kube-apiserver can't boot up after kubeadm certs renew, OIDC connection refused
In a Kubernetes 1.25 with 2 Ubuntu controllers cluster, after detecting the expiration of certificates inside /etc/kubernetes/pki we launched 'kubeadm renew all' command on both the controller nodes, and we rebooted the nodes.
After the reboot, the kube-apiserver is not able to start up anymore and its docker container keeps crashing.
The docker logs complains about not reaching the OIDC server (it is a keycloak pod), so it seems like the OIDC connector is mandatory for starting the api-server:
{"log":"I0805 13:24:51.011009       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 12 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2024-08-05T13:24:51.011063776Z"}
{"log":"I0805 13:24:51.011027       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 11 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PodSecurity,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2024-08-05T13:24:51.011072396Z"}
{"log":"I0805 13:24:51.013060       1 etcd.go:292] \"Using watch cache\" resource=\"customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io\"\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2024-08-05T13:24:51.013133647Z"}
{"log":"E0805 13:25:01.010261       1 oidc.go:335] oidc authenticator: initializing plugin: Get \"https://10.10.2.123/admin/master/console/#/MYORGANIZATION/.well-known/openid-configuration\": dial tcp 10.10.2.123:443: connect: connection refused\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2024-08-05T13:25:01.010450438Z"}
{"log":"E0805 13:25:11.009612       1 oidc.go:335] oidc authenticator: initializing plugin: Get \"https://10.10.2.123/admin/master/console/#/MYORGANIZATION/.well-known/openid-configuration\": dial tcp 10.10.2.123:443: connect: connection refused\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2024-08-05T13:25:11.009785705Z"}

The kubelet logs says that kubelet cannot find the 1st kubernetes node (expected as kube-apiserver is not working):
Aug 05 16:33:21 mynode1hostname kubelet[3556]: E0805 16:33:21.973266    3556 kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"mynode1hostname\" not found"
Aug 05 16:33:22 mynode1hostname kubelet[3556]: E0805 16:33:22.032233    3556 controller.go:144] failed to ensure lease exists, will retry in 7s, error: Get "https://10.10.2.123:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/mynode1hostname?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.10.2.123:6443: connect: connection refused
Aug 05 16:33:22 mynode1hostname kubelet[3556]: E0805 16:33:22.074320    3556 kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"mynode1hostname\" not found"
Aug 05 16:33:22 mynode1hostname kubelet[3556]: E0805 16:33:22.083596    3556 file.go:182] "Provided manifest path is a directory, not recursing into manifest path" path="/etc/kubernetes/manifests/BACKUP"
Aug 05 16:33:22 mynode1hostname kubelet[3556]: E0805 16:33:22.174820    3556 kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"mynode1hostname\" not found"

The kube-apiserver.yaml file is pretty standard. We've tried to remove the OIDC dependency by commenting its lines with no avail as the kubelet still complains about not reaching the OIDC (so the OIDC seems as circular dead loop as the kubelet cannot start without OIDC and Keycloak pod cannot start due to kubelet fail and so on):
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 10.10.2.123:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=10.10.2.123
    - --anynomous-auth=true
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --audit-log-path=/var/log/kube-apiserver.log
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --token-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/passwords.csv
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
      #    - --oidc-issuer-url=https://10.10.2.123/admin/master/console/#/MYORGANIZATION
      #    - --oidc-client-id=Kubernetes
      #    - --oidc-username-claim=username
      #    - --oidc-groups-claim=group
    - -v=5
    image: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.11
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 10.10.2.123
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        host: 10.10.2.123
        path: /readyz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 10.10.2.123
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
      name: etc-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: etc-pki
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-share-ca-certificates
status: {}

Did someone find a similar case after renewing the Kubernetes certs and rebooting the nodes?
I tried to search in the SO with no clear evidence of this case.

For anyone who may encounter a similar issue:
The oidc dependency was requiring a keycloak functioning endpoint.
In our case, the keycloak was not functioning properly (we discovered in its logs, issues connecting to its postgresdb).
We disabled the oidc parts entirely from the kube-apiserver and in this way asked the api-server to start up without oidc/sso/keycloak integration.
In order to "force" the kube-apiserver to start again from the fresh yaml in /etc/kubernetes/manifests we saw that moving out and moving in yamls file from and in /etc/kubernetes/manifests somehow "triggers" the redeploy of the kube-apiserver docker (along with restarting the kubelet service).
In any case, the kubelet is reading continuously from the /etc/kubernetes/manifests (if you haven't changed the yaml path from default) so commenting out the oidc lines from the kube-apiserver is enough to spin up a new kube-apiserver docker.

Based on the question title, the issue seems to be a mismatch in certificates after the renewal and a potential configuration issue related to the OIDC integration.
Follow below  troubleshooting steps :

Ensure the certificate paths specified in the kube-apiserver configuration file (/etc/kubernetes/pki/) are correct and point to the newly generated certificates after the renewal and also check kube-apiserver's log file for specific error messages related to certificate validation.
Restart both controller nodes and kube apiserver pods. By doing this kube-apiserver should be able to start without relying on OIDC.
After system reboot, please make sure Keycloak pod works fine that can be verified by executing:Kubectl get pods -n kube-system
Make sure that keycloak service is exposed and accessible from the kube-apiserver pods. Use kubectl get service -n kube -system for checking the service and its endpoints.
Make sure you have checked network connectivity issues or other firewall or network policies that might block communication between the kube apiserver pods and keycloak service.
And if all these troubleshooting steps don’t work, then it means your setup needs OIDC and in such case I would suggest starting all over again to reinstall your kubernetes cluster with kubeadm init & kubeadm join on each controller node that may recreate the cluster state having got updated certificates to perhaps fix configuration issues as well.

Refer to this Github link  and Medium blog written by Bob Killen for more information.
